# spark: mappartition (parallel) + iterable (seq) vs while (seq) + map (parallel)

Tags: dictionary, apache-spark, key, partition

I have the following dilemna

I play with a RDD[(key0, data),(key1, data),(key0, data),..]
And I need to aggregate all data with similar keys before processing them by key

The first idea is to iterate over all different keys, and for each key, to retrieve (filter) all data mapped with the same key.. By this way, I can still perform parallel operations on the resulting structure (RDD), but it is inefficient if there are many keys (many iterations)..

The second idea is to partition data with a custom partitioner (as many partitions as distinct keys).. And then, do a mappartition.. But then, within each partition, we can only process data sequentially (Iterable..).. Inefficient if there many data..

Any idea? Or does exist a third magic idea?
Thanks

Comment: What do you want to do? group by key and what's next?

Comment: what kind of aggregations do you need to perform on the data?

Comment: The [tag:processing] tag should only be used for questions about the Processing language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help..

So, by aggregating data (by key) in the same collection (Buffer, List, ...),
I could perform regressions on them.. But the resulting collections could be too large for residing on a single node

Answer (score 0):

The question lacks the level of detail required to be certain, but it looks like `rdd.reduceByKey(aggregation)` or `rdd.aggregateByKey(zero)(aggregator,reducer)` would fit the needs.